# What does winkey + slash & backslash do?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

1. Is winkey+\ a defined hotkey in Windows10?
2. Is winkey+/ a defined hotkey in Windows10?

I am trying to use these in my macro manager but it is refusing to allow me to enter them. Which usually indicates that they are taken by something else.

Google isn't giving me the answer so thought I'd ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Windows`+`/` = Begin IME (Input Method Editor) reconversion, at least it was in the past.

I could not find anything about `windows`+`\`. It may be that the `\` is used a lot to escape characters behind it, so it could be that you should define `\\` instead of a single backslash.